# Getting SQLite from remote and store locally in Flutter

Tags: flutter, sqlite

Im setting up an app, a sort of local guide; my idea is to have the app to work even offline, by storing most of its content locally in a SQLite database.
Since i already have the content in a database, i'd like to retrive that database from my server and store it; i already know how to get data from an API and save it in the local database, but i think getting the db file from remote and cloning in the app its lesse labour intensive.
At the moment running the app the first time i can create the empty database, and save the date of the action, i can also GET from http the database, but i dont know where to save it to have my local database use this data (to be honest i don't even know if it is possible), also i would like to periodically check on remote to see if the data was updated and get a fresh db to override the one present.
Anyone know if and where to save the db content from remote?

Thank you

Comment: Doable it is, but I don't recommend downloading the whole db solely for the purpose of updating , you will be wasting a lot of bandwidth and is not future-proof.

Comment: thats a good point, we are updating the DB twice a year (in the past 4 years structure was not changed), i probably come up with a intermediate solution, i would ship the empty db in the asset, on first run i will copy the db in the database location and dowload the content (as sql file, it is around 10megs) and execute it, another solution is to save while browsing remotely, but this way i will have offline access only to things i already saw